# Proposition logic, question about indirect proof.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This is the solution posted by my professor.

[image]

For the I.P from step 7) – 11), there’s a proof that can get A&A for that I.P , does this matter?
For 8), I’m assuming instead of 1, 5MP it's 5, 7MP.

```
7) A        IP  
8) ~~A      7 DN  
9) ~B       8, 2 DS  
10) A       9, 1 DS  
11) A&A     7, 10 Conj
```

I missed a class, so I'm not sure if this detail was went over, but I’m assuming that the indirect proof’s starting parameter can’t be used for the final P&~P conclusion right?

Now if that’s the case, and I write something like

```
6) A -> B   5 Simp  
--> 7) A        IP  
--> 8) B        6, 7 MP  
--> 9) ~~A      7 DN  
--> 10) ~B      8, 2 DS  
--> 11) B&~B    8, 10 Conj  
12) ~A      7-11 IP
```

If this statement is true, aren’t I able to find A again?

```
12) ~A    
13) ~B      6, 12 MT  
14) A       13, 1 DS
```

Wouldn’t this contradict with all the proof we just made?
And my last question is that if I ignore this, and use B for the final conclusion,

```
12) ~A
13) ~B
14) B       1, 12 DS
15) B&~B    13, 14 Conj
```

Can I use B again? Since I already used it in the second IP

Comment: You should not post the question as an separate image.

Comment: I kinda assumed the image would appear as an image embedded like a normal website

Comment: I do not know for what stupid reason new users can put link in question but not image.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see what's going on.   Your professor appears to be using Classical Logic with de Morgan's Laws (DM) and *modus tollens* (MT) preproved, and older names for the other rules of inference than I'm used to. (Also using $\&$ for conjunction...)

He is trying to show $A\vee B, \neg A\vee\neg B\vdash \neg (A\leftrightarrow B)$ using negation introduction.

Quickly now: the premises are $A\vee B$ and $\neg A\vee \neg B$, or equivalently $\neg (\neg A\& \neg B)$ and $\neg(A\& B)$ (by deMorgan's).   Assume $A\leftrightarrow B$; that is $A\to B$ and $B\to A$.   Should we further assume $A$, then we would deduce that $B$ (via modus ponens), but this contradicts the second premise.  So we've deduced $\neg A$. Having that we can deduce $\neg B$ (via modus tollens).  However having both $\neg A$ and $\neg B$ contradicts the first premise, so we must deny the assumption.

Hence we infer $\neg (A\leftrightarrow B)$ from $A\vee B$ and $\neg A\vee\neg B$.

---

So...

> For the I.P from step 7) – 11), there’s a proof that can get $A\&A$ for that I.P , does this matter?
>
> For 8), I’m assuming instead of 1, 5MP it's 5, 7MP.

Yes, that is so; you found a typo.

> I missed a class, so I'm not sure if this detail was went over, but I’m assuming that the indirect proof’s starting parameter can’t be used for the final P&~P conclusion right?

No, that's quite allowable, if you can do it. If assuming $P$ *does allow* you to infer the contradiction, $P\&\neg P$, then that is a valid indirect proof of $\neg P$.

> If this statement is true, aren’t I able to find A again?
> 12) ~A
> 13) ~B$\qquad$6, 12 MT
> 14) A$\qquad$13, 1 DS

That works too.

> Wouldn’t this contradict with all the proof we just made?

Yes it would, and that is good.

The argument is *exactly that* assuming $A\equiv B$ *contradicts* the two premises.   It doesn't matter whether you derive $A\&\neg A$ or $B\&\neg B$, or even $(\neg A\&\neg B)\&\neg(\neg A\& \neg B)$, from the assumption under the premises, as any contradiction will do.

> Can I use B again? Since I already used it in the second IP

You cannot access the statement of $B$ that is quarenteened inside the subproof.   However, you *may* derive a *new* statement of $B$, if you can from accessible statements.   Such was done from the just deduced statement $\neg A$ and the first premise using disjunctive sylogism: $\neg A, A\vee B\vdash B$.

Comment: This post cleared up a lot of my confusions, but there was one big one that I'm still confused on. I understand that the Indirect proofs are suppose to contradict to get the result. But since you said, it is allowed to use P to infer a P&~P contradiction. But I can find P&P, shown at my first indent, 11) A&A. I'm confused at this part, since I got a P&P result, wouldn't this be wrong? By contradicting I meant, contradicting to the rule of direct proof, as the result should be P&~P and not P&P right? I hope I got my thought across, the comment section is a little difficult to edit